# How to handle choice field with JPA 2, Hibernate 3.5

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, data-modeling, jpa-2.0

I have an entity with Integer attributes that looks like this in *proto code*:

```
class MyEntity:
    String name

    @Choices({1, "BSD", 2, "Apache", 3, "GPL"}
    Integer frequency

    @ChoicesSegment({1000, 2000, 3000}, {"BSD", "Apache", "GPL"})
    Integer type

    String getFrequency()
           return getChoice("frequency", frequency)
    String getType()
           return getChoice("type", type)
```

maybe this solution is more feasible:

```
class MyEntity:
    String name

    final static private Something? frequencyChoices = {1000, 2000, 3000}, {"BSD", "Apache", "GPL"}
    Integer frequency

    final static private String[] typeChoices = new String[] {"BSD", "Apache", "GPL"}
    Integer type

    @Choices(MyEntity.frequencyChoices)
    String getFrequency()
           return frequency)

    @IntervalChoices(MyEntity.typeChoices)
    String getType()
           return type
```

*get** accessors return strings according to this table.

```
value(type) HumanReadableString(type)
  1             BSD
  2             Apache
  3             GPL

min frequency         max frequency    HumanReadableString(frequency)
    0                     1000                rare
    1000                  2000              frequent
    2001                  3000                sexy
```

It should be possible to get all possible values that an attribute can take, example:

```
getChoices(MyEntity, "type") returns ("rare", "frequent", "sexy")
```

It should be possible to get the bound value from the string:

```
getValue(MyEntity, "frequency", "sexy") returns (2000,3000)
```

*edit*: ***purpose of all of this*** This methods should simplify the generation of forms and requests (of course this should not be view implementation bound)

*edit*: added how I would like to tell Java that some attributes are spécial so that it can generate get* accessors acordingly.

*edit*: added how to submit in the code the choices

*edit*: the only thing that I store in the db is integers, when I want to print them they should be converted somehow to their human readable string.

Comment: What can you change? Can you use enums? What parts must be dynamic? What parts are stored in database?

Comment: I don't know dynamic Java if it is exists, I will add some informations on how I would like it to be written. Maybe enums are fine but how should I use them ?

Comment: I didn't mean dynamic Java, I meant dynamic values (e.g. being able to add a new license without recompiling the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have additional info in enums:

```
public enum License { 

    GPL("GPL"),

    APACHE("Apache License");

    public License(String displayName) {
        this.displayName=displayName;
    }

    String displayName;

 }
```

Additional functions as required, but have a close look which functions are already provided by the Enum classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any hassle (but note, that the value in the DB will be the `ordinal()` value of the enums. So:

```
public enum License { GPL, APACHE, BSD }
```

`FrequencyChoices` could go into an `@ElementCollection`.

If you need human readable values, you may want to convert your Enum to an ordinary class, and persist it as a separate table, so you can add new licenses more easily to the list...

```
@Entity
public class License {
    @Id long id;
    String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to persist this but you can try following http://marekhalmo.blogspot.sk/2012/09/cool-java-enums.html

I would stick to enums.